# How to read/import training and testing images for multiclassification from a zipped folder in google colab? gdrive already mounted to gcolab

Tags: image-processing, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, training-data, multiclass-classification

I am fairly new to machine learning and deep learning. I am doing a student project wherein I am doing multiclassification image processing. Since, I do not have the recommended nVIDIA gpu for tensorflow (cannot buy it atm either), I am using Google colab instead and their virtual GPU.

I have mounted my gdrive to colab:
[image: gdrive mounting]

As you can see it shows 131 classes/subfolders in the training set. The 131 are names of different fruits - each fruit has 1 dedicated subfolder. There are a total of 40,000 images stored across these subfolders. Something as below:
[image]

Each fruit subfolder has images associated with the class and the images are named as 0_100.jpg, 1_100.jpg, 2_100.jpg.....

How do read and split these images into X-train and X_val and how do I create the associated y_train target name. Till date I have only worked with sklearn and keras datasets in jupyter lab, which are already sorted and named and I only had to import them.

Since, the dataset is downloaded from kaggle, do you suppose it is better to directly connect to kaggle from colab and create a json file?...like in this link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/an-informative-colab-guide-to-load-image-datasets-from-github-kaggle-and-local-machine-75cae89ffa1e

Please can someone suggest how to do this or point me to some relevant examples...much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataLoader from PyTorch, for example:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    # ...
    transforms.ToTensor() ])

train_dir = '/train_test/Training/'

# As you are going to split Training set into Train and Val sets, "Training" is your full_dataset
# Loading dataset from directory
full_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, train_transforms)
# Splitting into Train and Val
train_size = int(0.8 * len(full_dataset))
val_size   = len(full_dataset) - val_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(full_dataset, [train_size, val_size])

# Creating a data_loader
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( train_dataset )
val_dataloader   = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( val_dataset   )
```

In case you have you dataset splitted into Train and Val by other methods or don't want to use Val set, using `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` you load `train_dataset` and create a data loader directly and skip splitting part.

It automatically creates `X` (input image) and `Y` (labels) sets. Then, on train phase you can use `train_dataloader` in the following way:

```
# ...
for inputs, labels in tqdm(train_dataloader):
    inputs = inputs.to(device) # Your X-train
    labels = labels.to(device) # Your y_train
    # ...
```

It works in case you have following structure (if I got the way your data is stored clearly):

```
|-train_test
    |-Test
    |-Training
        |-Apple Braeburn
        |   |-0_100.jpg
        |   |-1_100.jpg
        |   |-...
        |-Apple Crimson Snow
        |   |-0_100.jpg
        |   |-1_100.jpg
        |   |-...
        |-...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :) . I was hoping to do it with Keras/tensorflow, but I guess I can use Pytorch (never used it before, but it looks straightforward....thanks)....    
So, basically inputs = X_train and labels = y_train and I should do the same for my test folder and get X_test and y_test.... are inputs and labels numpy array that I can use for input for training/testing a CNN/or similar model or will I need to convert them into nparrays???

Comment: @Wendy, in that way `inputs` and `labels` are transformed into tensors (`transforms.Compose`) and are suitable to be fed into your model like `preds = model(inputs)` and then `loss_value = loss(preds, labels)` during each iteration. For the testing phase you should load your `Test` set the same way (don't forget to disable gradient for test). All of this in case you will use `torch`.